# Recursion and Binary Searching

Tags: java, recursion, binary

So I was reading about Recursive searching in a binary search algorithm and I saw a line that says, that with every computation where you don't find the result, you cut the array you are looking through in half and create a new array. Is it really necessary to make a new array with every computation instead of adjusting the start and end index of the array you started with?

Comment: Where were you reading that?Normally for binary search, there is no need to create a new array.

Comment: there's not only no need, you really shouldn't do it, otherwise your space consumption will go from O(n) to ~O(n^2) (not a tight bound but you'd be heading towards there)

Comment: you can delete the old array, so you will save space after the copy.

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far. I was pretty curious about this. But why do I get downvotes exactly? My question is pretty legit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sure you can just adjust the start and end index. This is the implementation. What you are reading is an easy description of the algorithm, the implementation can differ if it still does the work.